# How to dynamically break pages when converting HTML to PDF

Tags: html, node.js, pdf

On my back-end application, I'm making a PDF using HTML content. The content is dynamic so I can't place manual page breaks for specific sections of the content. For example, if there is a paragraph with a heading and it does not fit into the remaining space on the current page That whole paragraph should go to the next page. I am using the `html-pdf-node` package to generate the PDFs. Is there a way I can dynamically add the page breaks to the `html`. Following is my PDF generating code:

```
import * as PDFDocument from 'pdfkit';
import * as pdfDoc from 'html-pdf-node';
import * as fs from 'fs';


export const createPdfFromHtml = async (content: string, pdfPath: string): Promise<string> => {
    const doc = new PDFDocument();

    doc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(pdfPath));
    doc.end();

    const options: pdfDoc.Options = {
        format: 'A4',
        // width: 595,
        // height: 842,
        path: pdfPath,
        margin: {
            top: 30,
            bottom: 30,
            left: 30,
            right: 30,
        },
    };

    const file = { content };

    await pdfDoc.generatePdf(file, options);
    return 'pdf generated';
};
```

Comment: Have a look a the CSS properties [`break-after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/break-after), `break-before` and `break-inside` by which you can influence page breaking in HTML. Then check if the HTML-to-PDF converter respects these as well.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen even this should be added dynamically since I can't guess before how the content will form.

Comment: But you said that you don't want page breaks within paragraphs nor between a paragraph and its heading. Can't such things be specified with these CSS properties?